# Criar gráfico boxplot de valores em classes

Tags: r

Tenho esses valores em um dataframe:

```
structure(list(NotaFinal = c(23.95, 25.4, 31.55, 25.4, 27.8, 
27.3, 31.85, 20.45, 31.95, 28.55, 20, 24.95, 14.45, 22.55, 25.65, 
10.35, 27.95, 21.45, 18.45, 21.1, 12.3, 22.65, 30.35, 27.4, 12.85, 
21.95, 26.25, 28.55, 24.3, 22.35), TempoConvertido = c("21.85", 
"32.88", "42.58", "44.24", "20.06", "29.93", "49.2", "22.71", 
"76.1", "25.76", "19.79", "32.87", "15.55", "62.4", "21.25", 
"12.89", "104.76", "15.35", "13.48", "24.47", "7.37", "22.73", 
"81.42", "24.25", "6.89", "42.4", "64.08", "49.71", "17.76", 
"16.62")), .Names = c("NotaFinal", "TempoConvertido"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Utilizo a seguinte função da biblioteca `fdth`:

```
distribuicaoDeFrequenciaTempoConvertido=fdt(as.numeric(dfTempoNota[,2]))
```

Ela cria 6 classes dos valores do atributo `dfTempoNota[,2]`, preciso criar um boxplot que correlacione os valores de `dfTempoNota[,1]` de acordo com as classes de valores geradas em `distribuicaoDeFrequenciaTempoConvertido`. Como posso fazer essa correlação de valores?

Comment: O que é `dfTempoNota`? Não está nos dados acima.

Comment: é o nome que dei ao meu data frame dos dados acima.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dfTempoNota <- structure(list(NotaFinal = c(23.95, 25.4, 31.55, 25.4, 27.8, 
                                            27.3, 31.85, 20.45, 31.95, 28.55, 20, 24.95, 14.45, 22.55, 25.65, 
                                            10.35, 27.95, 21.45, 18.45, 21.1, 12.3, 22.65, 30.35, 27.4, 12.85, 
                                            21.95, 26.25, 28.55, 24.3, 22.35), 
                              TempoConvertido = c("21.85", "32.88", "42.58", "44.24", "20.06", "29.93", "49.2", 
                                                  "22.71", "76.1", "25.76", "19.79", "32.87", "15.55", "62.4", 
                                                  "21.25", "12.89", "104.76", "15.35", "13.48", "24.47", "7.37", 
                                                  "22.73","81.42", "24.25", "6.89", "42.4", "64.08", "49.71", 
                                                  "17.76", "16.62")), 
                         .Names = c("NotaFinal", "TempoConvertido"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Transformei a variável `TempoConvertido` em `numeric`

```
dfTempoNota$TempoConvertido <- as.numeric(dfTempoNota$TempoConvertido)
```

Utilizei a função `fdt` para criar os intervalos de classe

```
distribuicaoDeFrequenciaTempoConvertido <- fdth::fdt(dfTempoNota$TempoConvertido)
```

A partir daqui eu acho o menor valor, o maior e amplitude dos intervalos que a função `fdt` cria e armazeno no vetor `breaks`. Depois eu crio o vetor `int` que possui o mínimo e máximo de cada intervalo. A função `findInterval` vai armazenar cada `TempoConvertido` dentro desses intervalos criados. Depois, só modifiquei o nome dos níveis dos fatores e criei o `boxplot`.

```
breaks <- distribuicaoDeFrequenciaTempoConvertido[['breaks']]
int <- round(seq(from = breaks[1], to = breaks[2], by = breaks[3]), 4)
dfTempoNota$fdt <- as.factor(findInterval(dfTempoNota$TempoConvertido, int))
levels(dfTempoNota$fdt) <- levels(distribuicaoDeFrequenciaTempoConvertido$table$`Class limits`)
boxplot(NotaFinal ~  fdt, data = dfTempoNota)
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Brilhante solução! Único detalhe que os valores das classes do eixo x ficaram ocultos devido a extensão dos números, nesta situação o mais apropriado seria criar uma legenda?

Comment: Isso fica a seu critério. Você pode incluir o argumento `cex.axis` dentro da função `boxplot` para reduzir o tamanho da fonte.

Comment: Se eu usar o argumento `cex.axis` para reduzir o tamanho da fonte, todos os valores só serão exibidos se a fonte ficar em um tamanho muito pequeno, que impossibilita visualizar. Existe algum argumento para "espaçar" os boxplot?

Comment: Sim, você pode especificar a posição dos boxplots com um vetor de comprimento igual ao número de boxplots no argumento `at`. Por exemplo `at = c(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11)`. [Aqui](https://www.r-bloggers.com/box-plot-with-r-tutorial/) tem um tutorial que pode ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas Rafael. Eu fiz o teste com o comando `at`, mas não achei que o resultado ficou muito agradável esteticamente, optei por usar o ggplot2 e descrever no eixo x o número do intervalo e utilizar a legenda para especificar os valores.